# xargs copy if file exists

Tags: linux, bash, xargs, cp

I got a string with filenames I want to copy. However, only some of these files exist. My current script looks like this:

```
echo $x | xargs -n 1 test -f {} && cp --target-directory=../folder/ --parents
```

However, I always get a `test: {}: binary operator expected` error.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to supply the `-i` flag to `xargs` for it to substitute `{}` for the filename.

However, you seem to expect `xargs` to feed into the `cp`, which it does not do. Maybe try something like

```
echo "$x" |
xargs -i sh -c 'test -f {} && cp --target-directory=../folder/ --parents {}'
```

(Notice also the use of double quotes with `echo`. There are very few situations where you want a bare unquoted variable interpolation.)

To pass in many files at once, you can use a `for` loop in the `sh -c`:

```
echo "$x" |
xargs sh -c 'for f; do
    test -f "$f" && continue
    echo "$f"
done' _ |
xargs cp --parents --target-directory=".,/folder/"
```

The `_` argument is because the first argument to `sh -c` is used to populate `$0`, not `$@`

Comment: Great solution, thanks. I am wondering why you don't use the "-n 1" argument. From what I thought, without it xargs is going to put in multiple arguments at a time, rendering `test -f ` useless.

Comment: With `-i`, the  `-n 1` is necessarily implied. Especially with multiple `{}` placeholders, `xargs` cannot pass in more than one file at a time (or the syntax to specify one of the many possible behaviors would have to be bewildering).

Comment: According to http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs the implied options are actually `-x -L 1` but the effect and rationale I believe is as described above.

Comment: The `--target-directory` must contain a variable. However, It seems to get lost when put in like `--target-directory="$var"/backup`. How can I do this?

Comment: Use double quotes to get `$var` expanded inside a quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` can only run a simple command. The `&&` part gets interpreted by the shell which is not what you want. Just create a temporary script with the commands you want to run:

```
cat > script.sh
test -f "$1" && cp "$1" --target-directory=../folder/ --parents
```

<kbd>Control-D</kbd>

```
chmod u+x ./script.sh
echo $x | xargs -n1 ./script.sh
```

Also note that `{}` is not needed with `-n1` because the parameter is used as the last word on a line.